Json for other ecommerce brands like wix, Bigcommerce, visualsoft etc
I'm trying to scrape product listings, prices etc. from various ecommerce shops online in a JSON format.
Now I know shopify seems to be pretty simple --> {STORE URL}/products.json
However how do you do it for Wix? Same goes for other platforms? I feel like there should be a really easy answer but can't seem to find it anywhere.
I've tried various versions of adding .json at the end of urls, i've also tried some out-of-the-box solutions but they're not very dynamic.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For BigCommerce, I'm not aware of any similar resource besides the XML sitemap at /xmlsitemap.php?type=products&page=n
